# LDAP memberOf returns no results

Tags: active-directory, database-administration, ldap-query, system-administration, memberof

I'm trying to create a custom query in ADUaC to help me index administrators in my system. I've narrowed down security groups that I need to list the members of, but I'm misusing the 'memberOf' attribute in some way which breaks the query.

```
(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=*)
```

The above query works fine to return all users, but the when I change the wildcard to anything else (ex. `(memberOf=*Administrators*)`), the query returns no objects.

I have confirmed that there is a relevant Security Group for this query to get users from. I am aware that it does not work for Primary Groups or nested users, and I am simply trying to get it working on a basic level right now. Anyone know how to have the code return users that are a member of the security group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the wildcard * character to filter distinguishedName attributes. The reason for this is the X.500 Standard.

http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/manual/109010000-ldap-filter-syntax.htm

Perhaps Powershell can be handy. Something like this could do the trick:

```
#for just one group
get-adgroupmember -Recursive -Identity "domain admins"

#for a batch of groups
$adminsgroups = "Enterprise Admins","Domain admins"
foreach ($admingroup in $adminsgroups)
{
     #with the recursive switch you get nested group members
     get-adgroupmember -Recursive -Identity $admingroup 
}
```

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for this! Do you know what script they are referring to in the referenced workaround? ("In this case we have to use a script-based solution which provides a workaround for this LDAP filter limitation.")(I'm not sure how general the 'we' is in this statement').

Comment: The author is referring to these articles. 
http://www.cerrotorre.de/faq-ex/faq-ex-setadr.htm
http://www.selfadsi.de/ldap-filter.htm#FilterDef
Unfortunately, the articles are in German, perhaps google translate an help.

Comment: I added some Powershell ideas for a script-based solution.